# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError using MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, compilation

I get this error when I try to compile my code. I am not sure what is wrong with it and I don't understand what is the error saying. Here is the error messaged followed by the lines where it says it errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at g52gui.C_login.<clinit>(C_login.java:9)
    at g52gui.V_login.<init>(V_login.java:6)
    at g52gui.V_login$4.run(V_login.java:181)
...
```

and the lines where it errors:

```
line 9 C_login (controller): private static final C_home controller_home = new C_home();

line 6 V_login (view): private final C_login controller_login = new C_login();

line 181 V_login (view): new V_login().setVisible(true);
```

It seems like the problem comes from the C_home but there is no compilation errors in there.

EDIT

I think the problem might be here, in C_login:

```
public class C_login {
    private static final V_login view_login = new V_login();
    private static final M_login model_login = new M_login();
    private final static C_home controller_home = new C_home();
    private static final C_registration controller_regi = new C_registration();
    private static final MySQLAccess sql_connection = new MySQLAccess();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        view_login.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static boolean login_button_clicked(String usrn, String psw){
        String login = M_login.login(usrn, psw);
        if (login == "ok"){
            controller_home.start_view(usrn);
            view_login.setVisible(false);
        } else if (login == "fail" ) {
            view_login.error_login();
            return false;
        } else {
            view_login.error_connection();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I delcare C_home controller_home as static so I can access it later. Would there be another way to go around this and could this be the problem ?

EDIT

here are the Initializer in C_Home:

```
public class C_home {
    private static final V_home view_home = new V_home();
    private static final M_home model_home = new M_home();
    private String username = "";

    /* attributes for 3d model */
    private BranchGroup sceneBranchGroup = null;
    private RotationInterpolator rotator = null;
    private Canvas3D offScreenCanvas3D = null;
    private ImageComponent2D imageComponent = null;
    private static final int offScreenWidth = 200;
    private static final int offScreenHeight = 200;
```

Comment: This error will come when there is an Exception is static method or block. JVM will wrap the Exception in `ExceptionInInitializerError` and throw it back. Provide relevant snippet of code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: To debug this issue you can separate declaration of controller_home and its instantiation. Use static initializer block and surround call to `new C_home()`

Comment: Surround initialisation in static block with try/cathch to place breakpoint there and debug faulty method.

Comment: Like `private static final C_home controller_home; {try{controller_home  = new C_home();} catch (Exception e){breakpoint here}}`. Problem is in C_home constructor. After you get some info on what ecxeption is the cause, debug this constructor further.

Comment: ITollu i get the same error.

Comment: Are there static initialisers in C_home class?

Comment: C_home loads fine on its own and i added the initializer in the post above

Comment: By the way, why do you need final members to be also static? They should not be constants. Use them as private final, not static, and initialize in constructor. I think, the root of trouble will get much clearer.

Comment: The `ExceptionInInitializerError ` should have a nested exception, which you haven't shown - that will give the details of what's actually going wrong. As an aside, now would be a good time to start following normal Java naming conventions.